# Reading a file using fs.createReadStream reads and extra trailing new line character, why?

Tags: node.js

I am learning node.js and was trying to read a file using different methods. Here is how I read it using pipes and it read no extra character from the file and worked as expected

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./file.txt', {
  encoding: 'utf8'
});
readStream.pipe(process.stdout);
```

But when I tried to read the same file using the following method, it resulted in an extra trailing new line character `\n`.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./file.txt', {
  encoding: 'utf8'
});
readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log(chunk);
});
```

Why is the second method resulting in a trailing newline character?

Comment: isnt it the trailing newline character by console.log itself

Comment: Exactly, I got it later, I should have used `process.stdout.write()` method instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete the answer it is the newline character by `console.log()` itself, not from file data